# Cassandra Racks show ? on Owns clusters

Tags: cassandra

I run Cassandra as Daemon on servers and I set endpoint_snitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, rpc_address to ip's server, listen_address to ip's server, seed_provider to list servers but on ./nodetool status show me 
[image]

What can I do to question marks disappear? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify a keyspace, the question marks will change to the percent of data owned for that keyspace.

```
nodetool status <keyspace name>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I have enabled Cassandra daemon I can not connect to ./cqlsh. For the ordinary course without gossip it possible to

Comment: already I solved the problem of cqlsh forgot to change the ip